How to implement Container Transform material design pattern for list items with Vuetify?
I'm speaking about the transition where an element of a list expands to fill the container without affecting other elements' positions:

https://m2.material.io/develop/android/theming/motion has a bigger version of the animation.
This seems to be a very versatile pattern, but I can't find anything similar in the documentation.
